# SQL query to find last created records in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have table called `Tbl_Dom`.

Columns are

```
ID, Original_id, name
```

Sample data:

```
Original_id    ID              Name
-------------------------------------
NULL          82051            DOM
82051         122575           SAT
122575        123598           sam
```

In this table, Id: 82051 has been created first in this table then 2nd record has been created based on the ID 82051 from first record (like this n number of records will be created) that will be referred ID: 122575.

When third record created the original Id will refer two 2nd record id: 122575 but basically its from the 82051.

**Question:** I know the old id: 82051 - by using this how to find most recently created Id:123598 from the table.

I have tried to arrive this but couldn't get the expected result.

```
Select id 
from dom t 
where original_id in (select original_id from dom t1)
```

My expected output is :

```
id: 123598  original id: 122575 name : sam
```

Comment: is ID  will be created always in incremental order?

Comment: No , It wont created the next increment number for those records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE combined with a window function, as in:

```
with
r as (
  select original_id, id, name, 1 as version from Tbl_Dom where ID = 82051
  union all
  select t.original_id, t.id, t.name, r.version + 1
  from Tbl_Dom t
  join r on t.original_id = r.id
),
x as (
  select
    original_id, id, name,
    row_number() over(order by version desc) as rn
  from r
)
select original_id, id, name
from x
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
original_id  id      name
-----------  ------  ----
122575       123598  sam
```

The recursive CTE is necessary to walk all the levels. In some cases you may need to walk a single level (or none at all), but in other cases it could be multiple ones.

**Bonus Query (for the same price)**:

Additionally, if (just for fun?) you wanted to get all the newer versions of a row you could do:

```
with
r as (
  select original_id, id, name, 1 as version from Tbl_Dom where ID = 82051
  union all
  select t.original_id, t.id, t.name, r.version + 1
  from Tbl_Dom t
  join r on t.original_id = r.id
)
select * from r order by version
```

Result:

```
original_id  id      name  version
-----------  ------  ----  -------
<null>       82051   DOM   1
82051        122575  SAT   2
122575       123598  sam   3
```

Comment: this one showing the null  in original id                                                                           :   original_id id name rn
NULL    82051  DOM 1 Im expecting  id: 123598 original id: 122575

Comment: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

subquery and left join can find the recent one

```
    with Tbl_Dom as
(
select null Original_id,82051 as ID ,'DOM' as Name
union all
select 82051,122575,'SAT'
union all
select 122575,123598,'sam'
) select a.id from
    (
    select id from Tbl_Dom
    ) a left join
    (
    select Original_id as id from Tbl_Dom where Original_id  is not null
    ) b on a.id=b.id where b.id is null
```

output

```
id
123598
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88efff96dfd9bee45c306918fe3f5cd3)

Comment: Thank you for the posting . Here you have selected the table records statically . My question is how we can slect these records from the id: 82051 from the table